# Finding x in $a^{x} \bmod  b = c$ when values a,b, and c are known?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

If values $a$, $b$, and $c$ are known, is there an efficient way to find $x$ in the equation: $a^{x} \bmod b = c$?

E.g. finding $x$ in $128^{x}\bmod 209 = 39$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the [Discrete Logarithm Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm_problem). If by "efficient" you mean "polynomial time general purpose algorithm", the answer is that none are known.

Answer (score 3):

A better reference than Wikipedia for the discrete logarithm problem is Andrew Sutherland's 2007 MIT Thesis [Order Computations in Generic Groups](https://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/38881). Here's an excerpt from p. 14 that provides a concise summary of the current state of knowledge.

[image]
[image]

Comment: For hand computation of small instances it is often convenient to use Shanks'  baby-giant step method, e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3444644/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3133816/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3323311/242)