# Compute the period of a decimal number a priori

Tags: number-theory, rational-numbers

I noticed that [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com), given an operation like $\frac{n}{m},\;n,m \in N$ that result in a periodic decimal number, computes really fast the length of the period.

E.g. $\frac{3923}{6173}$ has a period of 3086: [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3923/6173).

I was wondering how this computation is done: is there some method to do this (except the trivial one of executing the division and looking for a sequence repetition) ?

Comment: *Note:* i'm not a mathematician, I apologize if I have done some mistake with names, tags, etc..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The period is always a factor of the [totient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totient_function) of the denominator.  In your example, 6173 is prime, so its totient is 6172 and half of that is 3086.  I suspect Alpha is just doing the long division.  When the remainder at any step matches the remainder at a previous step you have found the repeat.  You can also find the repeat by finding the $k$ such that $10^k \equiv 1 \pmod {denominator}$

Answer (score 6):

Suppose that the fraction $\rm\,r\in (0,1)$ has a decimal expansion purely periodic of length $\rm\,k.\,$ Then $\rm\,10^k r - r\,\! =\,\! (10^k-1)\,\! r = n\,$ is an integer, since $\rm\,10^k r\,$ is simply $\rm\,r\,$ left-shifted by $\rm\,k\,$ places, so its digits after the decimal point are the same as those of $\rm\,r,\,$ so they cancel out in the subtraction, leaving an integer. Conversely, if $\rm\, r = n/(10^k-1)$ then $\rm\,10^k\,\! r = n  + r\,$ so $\rm\,r\,$ has period $\rm\,k\,$ (or a divisor of $\rm\,k\,$ if the cycle is not minimal).

Therefore, to find the minimal period of $\rm\,r = n/m\,$ we need to find the minimal $\rm\,k\,$ such that $\rm\,(10^k-1) n/m\,$ is an integer, i.e. such that $\rm\,m\,|\,n\,\!(10^k-1)\ \,$ (where $\rm\,a\,|\,b\,$ denotes $\rm\,a\,$ divides $\rm\,b).\,$ We may assume  $\rm\,n/m\,$ is in lowest terms, i.e. $\rm\,gcd(m,n) = 1.\,$ Hence, by Euclid's lemma, from $\rm\,m\,|\,n\,\!(10^k-1)\,$ we deduce $\rm\,m\,|\,10^k-1.\,$ Thus to find the least period we need to find the least $\rm\,k\,$ such that $\rm\,10^k \equiv 1\pmod{m},\,$ i.e. the order of $10,\,$ modulo $\rm\,m.\,$

If we know an integer $\rm\,k\,$ with $\rm\,10^k\equiv 1\pmod{\!m},\,$ e.g.  Euler $\,\phi(m)\,$ or Carmichael $\,\lambda(m)\,$ when $\,\rm m\,$ is coprime to $10,\,$ then the [Order Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/127118/242) implies that the order is a divisor of $\rm\,k,\,$ so if we also know the prime factorization of $\rm\,k\,$ then we can quickly compute the order by successively testing factors of $\rm\,k\,$ obtained by deleting primes - see the [Order Test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1188614/242). However, requiring prime factorization generally does not lead to efficient algorithms. For the state of the art on order algorithms see the literature cited in [this post.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/32353/242)

Comment: See also [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/61947/242)

Comment: What do you mean by "if the cycle is not minimal"?

Comment: Also, I'm trying to understand where you are going with "so r has period k (if the cycle is not minimal". I say this because you established in the first sentence that the period was k. I'm just trying to figure out what added information the quoted statement gives us.

Comment: @rocksNwaves For example, if it repeats every $3$ digits then it also repeats every $6,9,12,\ldots$ digits too. But we seek the least such period, i.e. the minimal cycle length.