# Rational doubt ( doubt in rational number)

Tags: rational-numbers

If there is a prime number x, if we reciprocate it we will get 1/x.

Reciprocal of prime number will be a rational number ,
Except 1/2 and 1/5 , 
every number which is reciprocal of prime number is a recurring non terminating decimal number.

Question- How to find that after how many digit recurring numbers will repeat ? 
How to find the recurring numbers?

Comment: Except 1/2 and 1/5

Comment: @MJD In above question link conditions are given . How to calculate without any condition ? Here in my question numerator is 1. So its different.

Comment: The period $n$ in which $\frac1p$ repeats is the smallest $n$ such that $10^n-1$ is a multiple of $p$. For example, $10^6-1 = 999999$ is a multiple of $7$, but $10^5-1$ is not, so $\frac17$ repeats every 6 digits.  However, no general rule is known that describes  the smallest such $n$ in general.

Comment: (The question has come up here many times before; [a search for “period of decimal”](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=period+of+decimal) will produce many relevant answers.)

Comment: For example, there are three answers at [Compute the period of a decimal number a priori](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140583/compute-the-period-of-a-decimal-number-a-priori)