# Periods of decimal representations of reciprocals of prime numbers? How to compute them for very large primes?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I wanted to know if there exists a formula or a script that generates the period length for the reciprocal of prime numbers. So for example $\frac17 = 0.142857142857142857$ so a period length of $6$.

I know there is a 10^k mod p but this takes too long for large numbers.

I have seen in this question:
[Compute the period of a decimal number a priori](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140583/compute-the-period-of-a-decimal-number-a-priori)

@Ross Millikan mentioned that "The period is always a factor of the quotient of the denominator" but I don't know of any literature behind this.

If you know anything about literature on this idea or a formula that can quickly calculate the period length for very large primes, I would be grateful if you can let me know

Update:
What I want to know more about is Ross's observation and why couldn't that be used to calculate the repeat digit period for very large numbers? So that's why I asked for literature on this.

Thank you.

Comment: This is just the order of $10$ $\pmod p$.  Thus, with $p=101$, for instance, $10$ has order $4$ and $\frac 1{101}=.\overline {0099}$.  And $10$ has order $34$ $\pmod {103}$ and $\frac 1{103}=.\overline {0097087378640776699029126213592233}$ is periodic with period $34$.

Comment: Should add:  it is not easy to calculate the order of a number modulo a very large prime.  If you don't need the exact period, you can always just use $p-1$.  It is true that $\frac 1p$ is periodic with period $p-1$ but it may happen that it has a smaller period (which divides $p-1$).  If you are able to factor $p-1$ then you can just check each factor.

Comment: Ross's observation comes from [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem). And lulu's is connected to the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function).

Comment: Please read more carefully. This is already answered in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/140643/242) in the thread you linked, which shows how it reduces to an order computation, and links to state-of-the-art literature on such.

Comment: I expanded  the prior mentioned answer. If anything remains unclear then please ask here or there.

Comment: Thanks for the that, as mentioned in the update of the question, I am really interested to if we know phi(p) is p-1 and phi(p) can be factorised (I assume, please correct me if I am wrong) then why can we not calculate the period?

Comment: Yes, given the prime factorization of some $k$ with $10^k\equiv 1$ (e.q. $k=p-1$) then you can use that to quickly compute the order of $10$ using the Order Test - as I explained in the linked dupe.

Comment: Sweet, so that means I could calculate the period of 1/p. Do you know of any python library or any other software that could calculate it for very large prime numbers?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://hr.userweb.mwn.de/numb/period.html) has some information about period lengths for primes under 2000.
And [this](https://hr.userweb.mwn.de/numb/periodp.html) talks about computing the period length for primes of "moderate" size.

I don't believe there is a surefire way of calculating it for large primes, there is some interesting information regarding period lengths in [this](https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a233979.pdf) paper, starting on page 31.

> The maximum number of digits in a period integer is one less
> than the prime number itself. Thus the maximum period length for
> the prime number 7 is 6, and that for the prime number 271 is
> 270. Actual period lengths may be less than maximum, but
> necessarily are sub-multiples of it.

Comment: I think the runtime of calculating the period just slows down horribly the bigger you go, no matter what. It's better than brute-forcing it by doing manual division.