# How to solve $\ x^{12}\equiv 87\pmod{101}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Can someone help me to solve the following congruent equation. I have tried to use Fermat's little theorem but failed to solve this:
$x^{12}=87(\mod 101)$

Comment: What's wrong with brute force?  It only takes a few seconds with a machine (including the programming time.  The actual computation is effectively instantaneous).

Comment: General note:  these problems tend to be really hard, computationally.  Brute force is an excellent approach, for numbers as small as these.  You could, of course, find a primitive root and work from there, but that's a lot more computation.

Comment: @lulu "Only a few seconds including the time for programming" - Somewhat exaggerated, but I agree to both comments.

Comment: @Peter  "Solve x^12=87 mod 101" is all it take in [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%5E12%3D87+mod+101)

Comment: @lulu True, but this is not actually programming. But I fully understand your point.

Comment: @Peter  Agreed. $\quad $

Comment: Doesn't there any other methods to solve this?

Comment: @user118413 Not sure whether my answer satisfies you. But I see no better solution.

Comment: @lulu Can integer square roots (modulo a prime) be calculated efficiently ?

Comment: @Peter  there's [Tonelli-Shanks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm) for primes.  Not even close to worth it here.  For composite moduli the problem is equivalent to factorization.

Comment: @lulu Au contraire, it is very easy by hand with the primitive root $2$ and baby giant steps - see my answer.

Comment: @BillDubuque  not bad...and if this failed, then of course you could try $3$, and so on.  Bound to hit a primitive root before too long.

Comment: @lulu Right. The mod arithmetic turns out to be super simple using $2$ (all can be done purely mentally in a few minutes).

Answer (score 2):

Let us try to use Fermat's little theorem

We know $$x^{108}=(x^{12})^9\equiv 87^9\equiv 36\mod 101$$ implying $$x^8\equiv 36\mod 101$$

This gives us $$x^{104}=(x^8)^{13}\equiv 36^{13}\equiv 95\mod 101$$

implying $$x^4\equiv 95\mod 101$$ Not sure whether we can simplify even further.

The integer square roots of $95$ modulo $101$ are $14$ and $87$, the square roots of $14$ modulo $101$ are $32$ and $69$ (two solutions) and the square roots of $87$ modulo $101$ are $17$ and $84$ (the two other solutions).

Answer (score 2):

*Algorithmically* let's use Shanks' [baby giant step](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby-step_giant-step). The Remark below shows $2$ is a primitive root $({\rm ord}\,2 = 100)$ so $\,87 \equiv 2^{\large n}\,$ is solvable, e.g. by baby-giant step, i.e. we solve $\,87\cdot 2^{\large 10j}\equiv 2^{\large k}\,$ for $\,0\le j,k < 10 = \lceil\sqrt{100}\rceil,\,$ by repeatedly mutliplying $\,87\,$ by   $\,2^{\large 10}\! \equiv 1010\!+\!14\equiv 14\,$ until we reach some $\,2^{\large k}.\,$ It requires $\,\color{#c00}4\,$  multiplications, i.e.

$$87\equiv-14 \overset{\large \times\color{#c00}{14}}\to 6\overset{\large\times\color{#c00}{14}}\to -17\overset{\large\times\color{#c00}{14}}\to -36\overset{\large\times\color{#c00}{14}}\to 1 $$

so $\ \smash[t]{87(\overbrace{2^{\large 10}}^{\large \color{#c00}{14}})^{\Large\color{#c00}4}}\equiv 1\overset{\large \times\, 2^{\LARGE 60}\!}\Longrightarrow 87\equiv 2^{\large 60}\!\equiv 2^{\large 12x}\!\!\!\iff$ $\! 12x\equiv 60\pmod{\!100}\!\iff\! n\equiv 5\pmod{\!25}$

Hence the solutions are  $\,x\equiv  2^{\large 5}\!\equiv 32,\,\ x\equiv 2^{\large 30}\!\equiv 14^{\large 3}\!\equiv 17\,$ and their negatives $(\times\, 2^{\large 50}\!\equiv -1)$

**Remark**  $ $ We skipped an optimization in order to better show the general method. Namely, at the start we already have $\,87\equiv -14\equiv -2^{\large 10}\equiv 2^{\large 60}\,$  by $\,-1\equiv 2^{\large 50},\,$ by $\,{\rm ord}\,2 = 100.\,$

To *prove* $\,{\rm ord}\,2 = 100,\,$ by the [Order Test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1188614/242) it suffices to show that $\,2^{\large 100/p}\!\not\equiv 1$ for all primes $\,p\mid 100,\,$ i.e. $\,2^{\large 20}\!\not\equiv 1,\, $ $2^{\large 50}\!\not\equiv 1.\,$ That's easy: $\,2^{\large 20}\!\equiv 14^{\large 2}\!\equiv 196\equiv -6,\,$ so $\,2^{\large 50}\!\equiv 14(-6)^{\large 2}\!\equiv 17(-6)\equiv -1$

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3444644/242) for another worked example.

Answer (score 0):

Numbers congruent to $87 \pmod {101}$ are $87,\; 87+101=188,\; 87+2\times 101=\color{red}{289}, ...$

and $87-101=-14,\;87-2\times 101=-115,\;87-3\times 101=\color{blue}{-216},...$

Note that therefore $17^2=289 \equiv87\pmod{101}$
and $(-6)^3=-216 \equiv 87 \pmod{101}.$

Furthermore $17\times6=102 \equiv 1 \pmod{101}.$

Therefore $17^5\equiv17^2/6^3\equiv -1 \pmod{101}.$

Thus $17^{12}=17^{10}\times17^2=(17^5)^2\times17^2\equiv87 \pmod {101},$

so $x=17$ is a solution to $x^{12}\equiv87\pmod{101}$.

Comment: I realize I found a solution but not all solutions.

Comment: The solutions are $\pm17,\,\pm 32$, easily computable by baby-giant step - see my answer.