# Solving for $x$ in discrete logarithm

Tags: modular-arithmetic, discrete-logarithms

$$9 = 2^x \text{ mod } 11$$

How do you use a calculator to obtain this value?

The $x$ is an integer.
Used in Diffie–Hellman key exchange algorithm.

Comment: The numbers are so small that brute force works rapidly.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm

Comment: In pari/gp calculator (https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/gp.html) enter `m=Mod(2,11);znlog(9,m,znorder(m))` and get `6`. Verify `m=Mod(2,11);m^6` and get `Mod(9, 11)`.

Comment: You can do it counting powers of $2$ on your fingers (reduce mod $11$ as you go).

Comment: Square $\ 2^3\equiv -3.\ $ More generally you can use [Shanks Baby Giant Step](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3133816/242)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We check by hand and get $2^{6} \equiv 9 \pmod{11}.$

By Fermat's little theorem, $2^{10} \equiv 1 \pmod{11}.$

$2^{10n+6}\equiv 2^{6} (2^{10})^{n}\equiv2^{6}\equiv9 \pmod{11}.$

Hence $x=10n+6$ for all $n\in\Bbb Z.$