# Find an exponent $b$ such that $4^b \equiv 34\pmod{107}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, discrete-logarithms

Find a b such that:

$4^b \mod 107 = 34$

My first thought is to use F.L.T.

$$4^{106} \mod 107 \equiv  1 \mod 107$$
$$34*(4^{106}) \mod 107$$

but seems a little unnessicary...

Any thoughts on where to go from here?

Comment: This looks like a [discrete logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) problem

Comment: Where did you get this problem? It can't be done by paper in a short time, as far as  I see,  unless $b$ is very small (it's not, $b= 15$ is the smallest positive solution).

Comment: @аст Actually it can be done quickly by hand - see my answer for one way.

Comment: by FLT you get $2^{106}=4^{53}\equiv 1\bmod 107$ actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an instance of the difficult [discrete logarithm problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/32353/242), but it is small enough that it is amenable to hand computation.

*Algorithmically* let's use Shanks' [baby giant step](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby-step_giant-step). By below $2$ is a primitive root $({\rm ord}\,2 = \color{darkorange}{106})$ so $\,34 \equiv 2^{\large n},\,$ and we seek $\,34\cdot 2^{\large -11j}\equiv 2^{\large k}$ for $\,0\le j,k < 11 = \lceil \sqrt{\color{darkorange}{106}}\:\!\rceil,\,$ by repeatedly scaling $\,34\,$ by   $\,2^{\large -11}\!\equiv \color{#0a0}{50}\,$ (by Remark) till we reach some $\,2^{\large k}\equiv 1,\color{}2,4,8,16,32,64,21,\color{#c00}{42},84,\color{#90f}{61},\,$ i.e.

$$34 \overset{\large \times\color{#0a0}{50}}\to 95\overset{\large\times\color{#0a0}{50}}\to \color{#c00}{42\equiv 2^{\large 8}}\qquad $$

so $\ \smash[t]{34(\overbrace{2^{\large -11}}^{\large \color{#0a0}{50}})^{\Large\color{}2}}\equiv \color{#c00}{2^{\large 8}}\overset{\large \times\, 2^{\LARGE 22}\!}\Longrightarrow 34\equiv 2^{\large 30}\!\equiv 2^{\large 2b}\!\!\!\iff$ $\! 2b\equiv 30\pmod{\!\color{darkorange}{106}}\!\!\iff\! \bbox[5px,border:1px solid #c00]{b\equiv 15\pmod{\!53}}$

**Remark**  $ \bmod 107\!:\,\ 2^{\large 11}\! \equiv 2(\color{#90f}{61})\equiv 15\  $ so applying [Gauss's algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/174687/242)

$$2^{\large -11}\equiv \dfrac{1}{15}\equiv \dfrac{7}{105}\equiv \dfrac{-100}{-2}\equiv \color{#0a0}{50}$$

To *prove* $\,{\rm ord}\,2 = \color{darkorange}{106},\,$ by the [Order Test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1188614/242) it suffices to show that $\,2^{\large 106/p}\!\not\equiv 1$ for all primes $\,p\mid 106,\,$ i.e. $\,2^{\large 2}\!\not\equiv 1,\, $ $2^{\large 53}\!\not\equiv 1,\,$ which is true.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3133816/242) for another worked example.

Comment: Thanks, Bill. This is a great answer.

Comment: Ah, I see, that is nice. One to keep in mind!

Comment: @BillDubuque in the line: "so $\ \smash[t]{34(\overbrace{2^{\large -11}}^{\large \color{#0a0}{50}})^{\Large\color{}2}}\equiv \color{#c00}{2^{\large 8}}\overset{\large \times\, 2^{\LARGE 22}\!}\Longrightarrow 34$..." why is $2^8$ multiplied by $2^{22}$?

Comment: @Raoul to solve for $34$ we need to cancel the factor of $\,(2^{-11})^2 = 2^{-22}\,$  on the left side (by scaling by its inverse $\equiv 2^{22})\ \ $

Comment: Ah. I see: $(50^2)^{-1}  \equiv 2^{22} \equiv 11 \mod 107$. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Raoul it's just $\ \large 34\cdot 2^{\large -n} = 2^{\large 8}\overset{\large \times 2^{\Large n}}\Longrightarrow\, 34 = 2^{\large n+8}\,$ for $\,n= 22.\,$ We don't need to know the value of $\,2^n\,$ to deduce that.

Answer (score 0):

tedious ( and potentially error prone, corrected before posting) way :

$$4^{b-1}\equiv 62\implies 4^{b-2}\equiv -38\implies 4^{b-3}\equiv 44\implies 4^{b-4}\equiv -96$$$$\implies 4^{b-5}\equiv -24\implies 4^{b-6}\equiv  -6\implies 4^{b-7}\equiv 52\implies 4^{b-8}\equiv -94$$$$\implies 4^{b-9}\equiv 30  \implies 4^{b-10}\equiv -46\implies 4^{b-11}\equiv 42\implies 4^{b-12}\equiv 64$$$$\implies 4^{b-13}\equiv 16\implies 4^{b-14}\equiv 4\implies 4^{b-15}\equiv 1\pmod {107}$$

This is based on the following.

- if $c$ is odd, turn into $-(107-c)$
- if $c$ is $4k+2$ , divide by 2 before doing the previous step, and divide by 2 again.
- if $c$ is $4j$ divide by 4 .

  Fermat isn't looking so bad anymore. With a little knowledge, like $2^{2b}\equiv 4^b$ restricting $b$, or knowing you can  modular sqrt 34; and figure the results discrete log for base 2, it's not so bad.  tedious sure, bad, unnecessary, yes, but useful.

Comment: of course, looking at $y=mx+b$ form allows you to show it's a 2 mod 4 multiple of 107 forcing $b$ to over 4 in 2 steps.

Comment: 105060 is the lcm of all the primes dividing the differences and that could push b>9 for example.